# random sample sets to create cross validation and training set based on a label

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract random samples 60:20:20 from a training set to create train, cross validation and test set.

I have used the following code to :

```
 train=data.sample(frac=0.6)
 trcv=data.drop(train.index)
 test=trcv.sample(frac=0.5)
 cv=trcv.drop(test.index)
```

However I realized that my training set is a supervised learning data and the last column of the dataframe contains a label Y ( column name) with values 1 or 0.

The way i want to create the training, test and cross validation set is that I want to assign .99:.1 of samples with y=0 and y=1 and assign it to the training set. This implies that if the training set has 100 records, i want 99 records to be y=0 and just one record to be y=1.

The remaining 99%  records with y=1 need to be split btw cross validation and test set as 45%, 44%

One possible way of doing is to create a dataframe containing a copy of records with column Y with value of 1 and then drop all the records from the master dataframe with y=1.

```
Y1=data[data.iloc[:,8]==1]
data=data[data.iloc[:,8]!=1]
```

Then apply the above the sample distribution to cv, test and training set.

```
 train=data.sample(frac=0.6)
 trcv=data.drop(train.index)
 test=trcv.sample(frac=0.5)
 cv=trcv.drop(test.index)
```

Now sample out 0.1:0.44:0.45 from the dataframe with y=1

```
ycvT=Y1.sample(frac=0.99)
ytr=Y1.drop(ycvT.index)
ytest= ycvT.sample(frac=0.45)
ycv= ycvT.drop(ytest.index)
```

This would create 3 different dataframes containing y=1.

```
Now I can add them to the training , cross validation and test set.
train=train.append(ytr)
train=train.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

.. and for cv and test set.

I was wondering if there is a smarter ( shorter) way of doing this. I want to restrict myself to pandas, numpy and scipy .

any tips ?. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y = data.iloc[:, -1].values
g = data.groupby(y)

frac = .2

ones = g.get_group(1).sample(frac=frac)
zero = g.get_group(0).sample(len(ones) * 99)

train = pd.concat([ones, zero]).sample(frac=1)
```

Comment: that is great!. should the frac=0.1 ?.

Comment: @sunny frac is whatever portion of ones you want to pull